# Oscillation and Hölder continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am studying a proof of a theorem. And I have the following situation in the proof:

Consider $\Omega$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb R^n$ and $u: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a function satisfying:

$$\operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,R)} u \leq (1-\delta) \operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,4R)},$$ for all ${B(x_0,R)} \subset \Omega$ for some $0<\delta <1$ ($\delta$ is independent of the open ball).

The book says: *Iterating* this inequality we have that $u$ is Hölder continuous.

Someone can help me understand the proof in the part of the "Iteration".

Thank you!

Comment: Where in what book?

Comment: the book is : Fine Regularity of Solution of Elliptic Partial Differential Equation   - Authors: Jan Maly  and William P. Ziemer

Comment: Thank you.  In case anyone has access to the book and would like to see more context, could you please share *where* this appears in that book?  E.g., what chapter, or page, or theorem number?

Comment: the page is 126  . the number of the theorem is 2.114. sorry for my error. sorry ...

Comment: Thank you very much! (There's no need to apologize.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer to write the inequality as 
$$\operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,4^{-1}R)} u \leq (1-\delta) \operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,R)} \tag1$$
Iteration means that applying (1) with $B(x_0,R)$ replaced by $B(x_0,4^{-1}R)$, then replaced by $B(x_0,4^{-2}R)$, etc., and then chaining these inequalities together. Thus, 
$$\operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,4^{-2}R)} u \leq (1-\delta) \operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,4^{-1}R)} u \leq (1-\delta)^2 \operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,R)} \tag2$$
and in general, 
$$\operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,4^{-k}R)} u \leq (1-\delta)^k \operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,R)} \tag3$$

Inequality (3) can be written in the form of the Hölder condition. Indeed, let $\alpha>0$ be the number such that $(1-\delta)=4^{-\alpha}$. Given $x$ near $x_0$, let $k$ be the integer such that $4^{-k-1}\le |x-x_0|< 4^{-k}R $. By (3), 
$$|u(x)-u(x_0)|\le (1-\delta)^k \operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,R)} \le C |x-x_0|^\alpha \tag4$$
where $C=4^\alpha \operatorname{osc}_{B(x_0,R)}$ is independent of $x$. Thus, $u$ is  Hölder continuous.